# Linq: comparison with nonexisting value should not cause the exception, but it does

Tags: .net, linq

Given I don't know if the parameter will be null or not and I want to use it in the following way:
if Param != null then compare with its id
if Param == null then compare with null.

Something like that:

```
var c = from cat in context.Categories
where ParamCat != null && cat.ParentId == ParamCat.Id 
||
ParamCat == null && cat.ParentId == null
select c;
```

If ParamCat is null as soon as I try to get something from c (for example c.Count()) it throws the exception.

Usually when we use some kind of condition it stop comparison as soon as condition fail especially if we use AND. For example this code will not cause any exception:

```
if (ParamCat != null &&  cat.ParentId == RaramCat.Id)
{
}
```

If so, why the linq code above throw exception? (Null reference)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to group your `&&` expressions with parentheses in order to get the compiler to evaluate them in that order:

```
var c = from cat in context.Categories
where (ParamCat != null && cat.ParentId == ParamCat.Id)
||
(ParamCat == null && cat.ParentId == null)
select cat;
```

Comment: Don't have editing privileges, but should be "select cat" rather than "select c".

Comment: @lukiffer: Indeed, it should be. That's what I get for copying and pasting the OP's expression without checking it for validity!

Comment: here is my working code: var cc = from c in context.Categories
                     orderby c.CategoryName
                     where (ParentCategory != null && 
                     c.CategoryParentId == 55) ||             
                     (ParentCategory != null && c.CategoryParentId == ParentCategory.CategoryId)//ParentCategory.CategoryId
                     select c;                                               The result is the same, I cannot figure out why??

Comment: Please ignore this code, it's wrong. That's weird. My first variant contains parentheses and I've added them but it didn't help. If I change ParamCat.Id for some concrete int (id) for example 55 it will work. I mean the count of element will be 0 but there is no exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var c = from cat in context.Categories
where (ParamCat == null && cat.ParentId == null)
  || (ParamCat != null && cat.ParentId == ParamCat.Id) 
select cat;
```

**(** and  **)** can make a big difference... :)

Comment: Doesn't work... there is still null ref exception. If I change ParamCat.Id to some concrete number (even non-existing) no exception is thrown.